# Почему скрипт обрывается?

Tags: bash, linux

Я запускаю скрипт удаленно на сервере:

```
./start.sh
```

или

```
./start.sh &
```

А потом закрываю терминал. В итоге скрипт обрывается (даже во втором случае). Как этого избежать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

запускать в screen или почитать man nohup

А вообще тут нехватает теоретических знаний о процессах.. если кратко,то когда вы заходите на сервер запускается оболочка с неким PID (номером процесса), все порождаемые в ней задачи имеют свой PID и PPID (номер родительского процесса). Как только родитель "умер", все его потомки также "погибают".. Это если кратко )